# How to remove second color of text from Rich Text Box c#

Tags: c#, winforms

in windows form application c# i make Rich Text Box invisible but 
to appear the text. the problem is the text appear with second color (white color). i want the text to be appeared with only one single color without second color or shadow. how to do that. when i used

> BackColor

then the text appear with only
one color, but if i use

> SystemColors.Control

rich text box to be transparent then the text appear with two colors
pleas anyone help me

Comment: I didn't see any option to add shadow to the text in the RichTextBox. Do you mean shadow of the border? (If yes, it can be removed if you set BorderStyle to None)

Comment: I habe no idea what you are talking about or asking. RTB is never transparent and its text never has a shadow. Show us the code and the result as well as a clear probelm description!

Answer (score 0):

i'm talking for text the rich text box will go transparent if make the form transparent then the text of rich text box will display but there will display
sticky second white color. that second color i want to remove, to display only 
one color.